# How import variables or functions declared in different javascript files for WebExtension?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

This issue appears in Firefox Developer Edition 53.0a2.

This take place in context of WebExtension development.

I have a lib script that export a simple variable.

#### my-lib.js

```
export const foo = 42
```

#### my-background-script.js

```
import foo from 'my-lib'

// ...
```

This throws a `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

How can I import variables or functions declared in different javascript files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 modules support is not far enough yet (source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import))

The use of [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is the option to transpile the code to a compatible javascript version.